# Finding a Ubuntu package for a sty file

Tags: packages, installing, tools, ubuntu, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

I've had this problem for a while now on Ubuntu. Whenever I have a missing `.sty` file (right now, it's `outlines.sty`), I have to go to synaptic and search for the .sty file. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Then, I search for it on this site or some search engine -- all basic adhoc stuff.

I was wondering if there's a regular/reliable way of finding if a .sty file is available for my distro. MikTeX has a great package manager and I wish we have something similar on Ubuntu.

Also, should this be here or on the askubuntu site? I haven't had this issue with any of the rest of Ubuntu so posting it here first.

Comment: TeX LIve 2011 has also a package manager. Remove the texlive version of ubuntu und install TeX Live 2011.

Comment: ...or if you want to keep your TeXlive 2009, I recommend "sudo apt-get install texlive-full" so you don't have to struggle with uninstalled packages.

Comment: With recent TL (2010 or 2011) you have `tlmgr` but you can install manually a package. You go at http://www.ctan.org/search/ then you download  the package and you put the files inside a "texmf" folder of your "home". If this folder does not exist, you create it.

Comment: Closed as a 'reverse dupe': we've now got a proper answer for the general case.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could use `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache search outlines
```

returns for me

```
libfont-freetype-perl - Read font files and render glyphs from Perl using FreeType2
...
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: ergänzende Pakete für LaTeX
```

You can see `texlive-latex-extra` here (even though it's not installed on my system, as `dpkg -l | grep texlive` shows - I installed TeX 2011 from tug.org), so `outlines.sty` may be included in this Ubuntu repository package.

You can find it out in detail by

```
apt-cache show texlive-latex-extra
```

which shows the package information, for example:

```
apt-cache show texlive-latex-extra | grep outline
```

returns

```
  courseoutline -- Prepare university course outlines.
  outline -- List environment for making outlines.
  outliner -- Change section levels easily.
```

You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Further, you could search and browse package information online, such as on http://packages.debian.org/ with a keyword, for example:

- http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tex

Comment: Further to Stefan's answer, you may want to do an "apt-get update" before doing "apt-cache search", and you might want to limit the search to Tex packages by using "apt-cache search outlines | grep texlive". (This is more of a comment really, but somehow I don't see a comment button.)

Comment: You need 50 reputation before you can comment on all questions/answers. I've flagged this "answer" so that a moderator may convert it to a comment.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Thanks! As suggested, I converted it to a comment.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: You really want to use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: As a last resort, both Debian's and Ubuntu's package sites let you search for particular filenames in packages. For example [searching for geometry.sty in oneiric](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=geometry.sty&mode=exactfilename&suite=oneiric&arch=any).

Comment: Thanks for the help. It would definitely work if there wasn't an ambiguity here. The package available in texlive-latex-extra is `outline`. What I needed was `outlines`. The answer is accepted though since it provides the correct method.

Comment: You may use also grep for not getting a large useless output
apt-cache search outlines | grep tex

Answer (score 8):

Although the outline package is bundled in `texlive-latex-extra` as shown by @StefanKottwitz, the [outlines](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines) package is not. It is the `outlines` package that seems to provide the 'outlines.sty' as referenced in the question.

Since `outlines.sty` isn't provided in an Ubuntu package, the simplest way to install the `outlines` latex package is to download it from CTAN (as linked above), and then unzip it into `~/texmf/tex/latex/` or some other place listed in `kpsepath tex`. If that description didn't make sense, see my [blog entry](http://nathanvan.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/managing-latex-packages-manually-in-ubuntu-12-04/) for blow-by-blow details.

This approach is much faster than liberating TeXlive from Ubuntu's package management system, but it doesn't quite get you as far as `tlmgr` will get you in terms of ease of use if you have a lot of extra packages not bundled with Ubuntu's TeXlive.

Comment: It would probably be better to make your local/personal 'texmf' mimic the branches of your normal/system texmf tree.  Putting, say, `outlines.sty` in `~/texmf/tex/latex/outlines/` and `outlines.pdf` and the `README` in `~/texmf/doc/latex/outlines` (and so on, for more complex packages).  This is why `.tds.zip` files are so great: they unpack into the 'correct' directory hierarchy.

Comment: @Nathan VanHoudnos: do you really mean "cran"?  i can't find outlines on cran at all, but it _is_ on ctan.

Comment: @wasteofspace Sorry, I meant CTAN. I'm an R user (and CRAN is where all the R packages live), so it came out wrong when I typed it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @jon that makes a lot of a sense. I'll update both my answer above and my blog post to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanVanHoudnos -- No problem.  Cheers!