# Find correct texlive package that contains missed files

Tags: texlive

I'm trying to find the minimum required `texlive` installation for Ubuntu 16.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/tex/texlive) in order to compile a document with LuaLaTeX.
Unfortunately, with `texlive` and `texlive-latex-recommended` I receive this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ucharcat.sty' not found.
```

How can I figure out which installation would be suitable and contain the required `.sty` files?

Comment: Do https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39771/105447 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/105447 help?

Comment: In particular `apt-cache search ucharcat` returns `texlive-luatex` for me.

Comment: With a minimal installation, errors like that will keep popping up. Instead of looking up the meta package, installing that, going on, looking up the next missing package, installing that .... i would just download vanilla TeX Live from TUG. I installed it last week on Ubuntu, it took almost two hours, but i have all i need.

Comment: Thank you, @gusbrs and @Johannes_B. `apt-cache` was very helpful to find the most commonly needed packages. This way, I could create a Docker image that is 2GB large compared to the 3GB of the `-full` installation. Well... Better than nothing :-)